# More job results behind proxy in England

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs, feedback, location

I noticed it several times that there are more results for certain searches on careers when I do the search from behind a proxy (England) than from home (Hungary)
Eg I searched python + remote only and there were 25 more results with an IP from England.
Why?

Comment: It assumes that you are not that interested in jobs that requires you to commute 2000 miles a day and learn another language.  Use the "Where" box to move your house.

Comment: I see, but if I'm only interested in telecommute (that's why I checked the remote box) why does it check my current location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because we geotarget listings based on your IP address. We basically target 4 tiers of X miles based on the amount of impressions a listing is getting. The less impressions, the farther out we go geographically. From what you describe, it's working as designed.

Another reason is that employers can opt in to target certain regions only. I.E. If a customer selects North America, an IP address outside of North America will not see their listing in search results.

Comment: From a telecommuting point of view though what relevance does the distance field have though?

Comment: @RichardTingle From an applicants stand point, not much. From the employers stand point it could be a lot. Just because a listing is remote, doesn't mean they're willing to hire worldwide. Some employers don't mind remote workers but still want to hire within their country.

Comment: ... or close enough to come every couple of weeks or so.